# WPF list<t> sort

Tags: wpf, collections

my first post here.

i have a list"<"frameworkelement> that i'm populating with a select process. each frameworkelement has a uid that holds its ZOrder.

i need to sort these by the ZOrder from lowest to highest. i can get this using a listbox and adding the Uid's like this:

```
            //Add Object Uid's
            ListBox lstTempOrder = new ListBox();
            foreach(FrameworkElement feObject in MainWindow.Data.SelectedObjects)
            {
                lstTempOrder.Items.Add(feObject.Uid);
            }
            //Reorder from 0 to above of the ZIndexes       
            lstTempOrder.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

but i need to do this with a List"<"FrameWorkElement> and Sort.

Here is the code where i populate the List"<"T> (SelectedObjects and CopyObjectsCollections are List"<"FrameWorkElement>" lists.

```
            foreach(FrameworkElement feObject in MainWindow.Data.SelectedObjects)
            {
                MainWindow.Data.CopyObjectsCollection.Add(feObject);
            }
```

i've looked at CollectionViewSource and IComparer but i can't really make any sense of it.

Comment: Instead of doing this manually, you should bind your ListBox to a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx), which allows to sort the items. See [Binding to Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i'm not sure what you mean by doing it manually. The listbox sort was just for a test and it works but i can't work out how to do the same on the List<T> "CopyObjectsCollection". I've never worked with binding before.

Comment: Binding is essential in WPF. You may start reading the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for the info on binding. for what i do since the start of wpf i haven't needed it. i'm only wanting to find one way of many to sort the List<T> like i do with the listbox. i'm sure it can be done without binding i feel. thanks for the responses anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might have miss-read your question, but if you just want to sort your `List<T>`, then why don't you just use the `LinQ` `OrderBy` method?

```
MainWindow.Data.CopyObjectsCollection = 
    MainWindow.Data.CopyObjectsCollection.OrderBy(f => f.Uid).ToList();
```

If that sorts it the wrong way round for your requirements, then you can use this:

```
MainWindow.Data.CopyObjectsCollection = 
    MainWindow.Data.CopyObjectsCollection.OrderByDescending(f => f.Uid).ToList();
```

UPDATE >>>

`OrderBy` is a `LinQ` extension method. Add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your class to use it. `f` relates to an instance of your `FrameworkElement` object. The above lambda expression basically means 'sort using the `Uid` property values'.

UPDATE 2 >>>

The `OrderBy` method does *not* alter the original collection... that is why my example sets the collection to the result of the `OrderBy` method. See this basic example:

```
List<FrameworkElement> elements = new List<FrameworkElement>();
elements.Add(new FrameworkElement() { Uid = "Object1003-1" });
elements.Add(new FrameworkElement() { Uid = "Object1002-2" });
elements.Add(new FrameworkElement() { Uid = "Object1002-1" });
elements.Add(new FrameworkElement() { Uid = "Object1001-1" });
elements.Add(new FrameworkElement() { Uid = "Object1001-3" });
elements.Add(new FrameworkElement() { Uid = "Object1001-2" });
string result = string.Join(", ", elements.Select(f => f.Uid));
elements = elements.OrderBy(f => f.Uid).ToList();
string orderedResult = string.Join(", ", elements.Select(f => f.Uid));
```

By comparing the values of `result` and `orderedResult` you can see that this orders them perfectly.

UPDATE 3 (and hopefully the LAST one) >>>

Dude, you need to learn about Lambda expressions... take a look at the [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) page at MSDN for more information.

```
elements = elements.OrderBy(f => f.Uid).ToList();
```

The `f` in this Lambda expression is declared *in* this expression before the '`=>`'. It is fairly standard to name these parameters with one letter like `Exceptions`, but we *could* name it anything:

```
elements = elements.OrderBy(frameworkElement => frameworkElement.Uid).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. it looks good but my List<Frameworkelement> doesn't seem to have OrderBy. i'm assuming that the "f" would be my "feObject"?

Comment: The namespace made a difference. i get a cannot declare for the first "F" "feObject" different meaning. i declared a new frameworkelement to use here that compiled but the list collection remains the same after the foreach. i tried it inside the foreach and after. i'm sure it's me as this looks like it should work. thanks for your help i appreciate it. The Uid for each element is like "Object1001-1" and "Object1002-2" and so on.

Comment: if i just use MainWindow.Data.CopyObjectsCollection.OrderBy(feObject => feObject.Uid).ToList(); after the foreach loop this compiles. not sure how as i'm not declaring feobject anywhere else but the order is still the same. nothing changes.

Comment: The "OrderBy" using "feObject won't compile in the foreach loop.                    foreach(FrameworkElement feObject in MainWindow.Data.SelectedObjects)
            {
                MainWindow.Data.CopyObjectsCollection.Add(feObject);
            }

Comment: Hard to write here. i can't parse anything out of the foreach loop to do anything with the collection after it either.

Comment: I translated that into my code and finally got it to work. Was harder as your info was not in the line of code i posted but got it there. thanks.